# Updating a label's text

Tags: javascript, c#

Is there a way to change a labels text every minute or so? If so how?

Im trying to make a label with how many online players there is on a specific server. I have made this in javascript and im new to C# so I need some help to get started. I'm grabbing the current players on the server from website which is in JSON. So first I need to parse the players from the other JSON info. How can I achieve that in C#? How can I make it update every minute and recheck if someone has joined/left the server? I hope you understand what I mean, else I will gladly explain it better in the comments.

The code I made in javascript looks like this:

```
 http.get("http://IP:PORT/players.json", function(response){
    let json = ""

    // receive everything from the server
    response.on("data", function(chunk){
        json += chunk
    })

    // if received everything
    response.on("end", function(){
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
            try {
                // we parse the response to an "array"
                const players = JSON.parse(json)

                // get the length (so count) and set it as status
                bot.user.setActivity(`${players.length}/64 online`, {
                    type: ''
                })
            }catch(e){
                console.log("Noget gik galt med Status")
            }
        }
    })
})
```

^
This is made for a discord bot :)

Sincerely,
Ossie

Comment: Unless you're doing Blazor, c# can't manipulate the DOM after it's been delivered to the client.

Comment: wrap your code inside a JavaScript function, and use window.setInterval [JavaScript Timing Events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use crontab or an infinite loop with an AJAX call that should do the job. If you are new to this and performance isn't too big of an issue I would suggest you first look into a loop. If you need more help let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a JavaScript function multiple times with a specified time interval

```
window.setInterval(UpdateLabel, 60000); //1 minute = 60000 miliseconds

function UpdateLabel() {
    http.get("http://IP:PORT/players.json", function(response){
        let json = ""

        // receive everything from the server
        response.on("data", function(chunk){
            json += chunk
        })

        // if received everything
        response.on("end", function(){
            if(response.statusCode == 200){
                try {
                    // we parse the response to an "array"
                    const players = JSON.parse(json)

                    // get the length (so count) and set it as status
                    bot.user.setActivity(`${players.length}/64 online`, {
                        type: ''
                    })
                }catch(e){
                    console.log("Noget gik galt med Status")
                }
            }
        })
    });
}
```